# Check decimal significant figure

Tags: c#, decimal, significant-digits

I want to check if a decimal has a value in the 4th significant figure.

```
//3 Significant figures
var val = 1.015;

//4 Significant figures
var val2 = 1.0155;
```

How can I test to see when there is a value in the 4th significant place.

I want to conditionaly display 3 or 4 decimal places depending if there is a non zero value in the 4th place.

What is the best way to do this?

Would this method work?

```
if((val * 10000) % 10 != 0) ...
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16083666/380384

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The silly answer would be: find the location of the `.` in your string, and then check the location+4.

The more serious would be, have a look at the [double formatting options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :)

You could use this formatting of double

```
//       using the   F4:                    1054.3224
```

and then if the last index of your string is 0, cut it out using substring.

---

As of your last edit (`if((val * 10000) % 10 != 0) ...`), yes, it should work ... Sudhakar suggested the same in his answer.

You should probably take whichever solution you go with, and put it in a helper method that returns an int, and then you can just use that in your code, helping your readability, and reusalibilyt :)

---

Go with Marks solution, simplest I guess.

```
double d = 3.40;
Console.Out.WriteLine("d 0.0: {0}", d);                     // 3.4
Console.Out.WriteLine("d 0.0: {0}", d.ToString("0.0"));     // 3.4
Console.Out.WriteLine("d 0.00: {0}", d.ToString("0.00"));   // 3.40
Console.Out.WriteLine("d 0.0#: {0}", d.ToString("0.0#"));   // 3.4
```

Do notice that if all you have is 3 or 4 digts after the `.`, the default would be truncated and removed as you can see if the first output above.

Answer (score 1):

1.Multiply the value with `1000` and then do `(value%10)` mod `10` for getting last digit in `3rd significant` value .

**Example : (3rd significant)**

```
        var val = 1.015;
        int val1=Convert.ToInt32(val * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine(val1 %10); 

Output: 5
```

2.Multiply the value with `10000` and then  do `(value%10)` mod `10`for getting last digit in `4 significant` value

**Example : (4th significant)**

```
        var val = 1.0157;
        int val1=Convert.ToInt32(val * 10000);
        Console.WriteLine(val1 %10);

Output: 7
```

Answer (score 1):

To learn about formatting your output check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx

To just check if there are 4 or more significant digits you can do

```
 if (inputString.Split('.')[1].Length > 3)
```

Of course, that isn't doing any error checking an could easily throw some exceptions but no need to clutter my answer with some basic bounds and nullity checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a custom format string:

```
double d = 1.2340;
string strDouble = d.ToString("0.000#");
```