# [C# Unity]1E+07 display as 10mln

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still learning C# and I'm making simple clicker game. My problem is that if some numbers reach 10 000 000 they start to display as 1E+07 (for example). The point is that I would like it to be shown as 10mln and higher(bln etc). And every time I try to do it I got a lot of errors. Can you give me some advices how can I do it?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class ping : MonoBehaviour {

public UnityEngine.UI.Text gpc;
public UnityEngine.UI.Text GoldDisplay;
public static float gold = 0.00f;

public static long toInt64()
{

    return Convert.ToInt64(gold);
}
public int goldperclick = 1; 


void Update(){
    GoldDisplay.text = "Ping: " + gold;
    gpc.text = goldperclick + "ping/click";
}

public void Clicked(){
    gold += goldperclick;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should implement your own type like Gold and override ToString() method for it

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Gold(10000));         //10000
        Console.WriteLine(new Gold(100000));        //100000
        Console.WriteLine(new Gold(1000000));       //1 mln.
        Console.WriteLine(new Gold(10000000));      //10 mln.
        Console.WriteLine(new Gold(100000000));     //100 mln.
        Console.WriteLine(new Gold(1000000000));    //1 bln.
        Console.WriteLine(new Gold(1500000000));    //1.5 bln.
    }
}

public class Gold
{
    public decimal Value {get;set;} 

    public Gold(decimal value)
    {
        Value = value;  
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if(Value>=1000000000) return $"{Value/1000000000} bln.";
        if(Value>=1000000) return $"{Value/1000000} mln.";
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Also you should choose numeric type you use wisely regarding to their max values and precisions.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555397/formatting-large-numbers-with-net) you can find some more details about large numbers formatting.

Comment: Good answer. I'd only like to add that this class can easily become a `FormattedNumber` and can be used for any of the things in clicker games that deal with large numbers.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use it.

Answer (score -1):

If you're only ever dealing with whole numbers, you'd probably be better off using a `long` instead of a `float`.

A signed `long` or (int64) can hold a value up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and will show every one of those values, while a float only provides 7 digits of precision - so with a value of `1,234,567,901` your float will only display `1,234,568,000` - which may not be what you expect (this can also be seen by printing out `float.MaxValue.ToString("0")` which only shows seven significant figures before filling with zeros).

An alternative if you need to use decimals would be to use a `double` which allows 15-16 digits of precision.

Comment: I wanted to do it like that, but when I'm changing gold form flaot to long i got error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'long'. So probably I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @Bajor You'll need to update any references to `ping.gold` to also be `long`s as well.

Comment: Still got this error here:
    public class ItemManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text itemInfo;
    public ping ping;
    public long cost; 
    public int tickValue;
    public long count;
    public string itemName;
    private long baseCost;
    void Start(){
    baseCost = cost;}
    void Update(){
    itemInfo.text = itemName + "\nKoszt: " + cost + "\nPing: " + tickValue +"/s";}
    public void PurchasedItem(){
    if (ping.gold >= cost) {
    ping.gold -= cost;
    count += 1;
    cost = Mathf.Round (baseCost * Mathf.Pow (1.15f, count)); //<-error}}

Comment: `Mathf.Round` still returns a `float` not a `long` so you'll still get that error there.