# How to convert a long to a string without having the scientific notation

Tags: powershell, unix-timestamp

I have a Powershell script that get the current time and convert it in Unix Timestamp. I would like to use this value as string parameter to make an HTTP request:

```
$currentTime = [math]::Round([double](get-date -uformat %s ((get-date).AddMinutes(-5).ToUniversalTime()))*1000)

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Delete -Uri "http://something?unmodifiedSince=$currentTime"
```

On some Windows machine it works fine but on some other (different Region settings?), I get the current time converted with the scientific notation. For example

```
http://something?unmodifiedSince=1.53835531189786E+17
```

How to avoid this conversion?

Comment: What does "on some other" mean?

Comment: @JacobColvin: Note the parenthetical "different Region settings?" clause, and it is indeed regional settings that are the source of the problem.

Comment: The way it's phrased made me think maybe he was running powershell on linux or something. @mklement0

Comment: @JacobColvin: I see. In PowerShell Core, on all platforms, including macOS and Linux, the problem would actually _not_ arise (and the code could be simplified) - see the bottom section of my answer.

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555397/formatting-large-numbers-with-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

- **In *Windows PowerShell 5.1* and *PowerShell (Core) 7+*** (.NET Framework 4.6+) a **much simpler solution** is now available, using [`System.DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds):

```sh
[datetimeoffset]::UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
```

---

**tl;dr**:

To **work around the problem with *culture-specific number formatting***, avoid a `[double]` *cast* and **use [`[double]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Double.Parse)** instead, which by default parses in a culture-*sensitive* manner:

```sh
[Math]::Round(
  [double]::Parse(
     (Get-Date -Uformat %s ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(-5)))
  ) * 1000,
  0,
  'AwayFromZero'
)
```

<sup>The `AwayFromZero` midpoint-rounding strategy ensures that `.5` second values are *always* rounded up, whereas the default `ToEven` strategy would situationally round *down*, namely whenever the integer part of the number happens to be even.</sup>

---

Indeed, your problem stems from the fact that:

- `Get-Date -UFormat %` outputs a *string* representation of the Unix timestamp
- and uses *culture-sensitive* formatting for the underlying floating-point number<sup>[1]</sup>, which means that in some cultures you'll get a string such as `'1538651788,87456'` (`,` as the decimal mark) rather than `'1538651788.87456'` as the output.

By contrast, PowerShell's casts always use the *invariant* culture, which *only* recognizes `.` as the decimal mark - and ignores `,`, which is considered a thousands-grouping character.

```sh
PS> [double] '1538651788,87456'
153865178887456  # !! , was IGNORED
```

Because the decimal mark was ignored and there are 5 decimal places, the resulting number is too large by a factor of 10,000 in this case (though note that the number of decimal places can vary, because trailing zeros aren't displayed).

If you then multiply that result with 1000, you get a number so large that PowerShell defaults its string representation to the scientific format that you've experienced:

```sh
PS> [double] '1538651788,87456' * 1000
1.53865178887456E+17 # !! scientific notation.
```

---

**[1] Optional reading: `Get-Date -UFormat %s` problems in *Windows PowerShell* vs. *PowerShell Core* (v6+):**

- Unix timestamps are *integers*, so `Get-Date -UFormat %s` shouldn't return a floating-point number to begin with. This problem has been corrected in PowerShell *Core*.
- Unix timestamps are expressed in UTC, but **Windows PowerShell only returns the correct value if you explicitly pass a UTC `[datetime]` instance**. This problem has been corrected in PowerShell *Core* (v6+).

  - E.g., to get the current time's Unix timestamp in Windows PowerShell, using

     `Get-Date -UFormat %s` is *not* enough; use `Get-Date -UFormat %s ([datetime]::UtcNow)` instead.

In short: This question's **problem wouldn't have arisen in PowerShell *Core***, because string representations of *integers* aren't culture-sensitive; additionally, the need for rounding goes away, as does the need to convert the input date to UTC, so that a PowerShell Core solution simplifies to:

```sh
# PowerShell *Core* only 
1000 * (Get-Date -UFormat %s ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-5)))
```

<sup>Note: This technically returns a `[double]` instance, but one without decimal places; use `[long] (...)` if an integer type is expressly needed.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I use this small function to get the current date and time as Unix Timestamp.
It returns an int64 so you should not have any trouble adding it in the url:

```
function Get-CurrentUnixTimeStamp {
    [DateTime]$epoch = New-Object System.DateTime 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, Utc
    [TimeSpan]$diff  = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() - $epoch
    return [int64][Math]::Floor($diff.TotalSeconds)
}

$currentTime = Get-CurrentUnixTimeStamp
Invoke-RestMethod  -Method Delete -Uri "http://something?unmodifiedSince=$currentTime"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could indicate explicitly `$currentTime` variable data type as `[Decimal]` instead of auto assigned `[Double]`. Like so:

```
[Decimal]$currentTime = [math]::Round([double](get-date -uformat %s ((get-date).AddMinutes(-5).ToUniversalTime()))*1000)
```

Comment: This won't help, because the real problem is that the `[double]` cast misinterprets the culture-sensitive `Get-Date -UFormat %s` result in cultures that use `,` (comma) as the decimal separator.
If the cast worked correctly, using the rounded `[double]` result as-is for stringification would work fine.